# Serving Static Files With Servant / Wai

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, servant

I am following this tutorial http://www.parsonsmatt.org/programming/2015/06/07/servant-persistent.html to create APIs through servant. I want to customize the server to serve static files as well but couldn't find a way to do it.

I am using the `stack` build tool.

I modified the `Main.hs` file's run to include `static` (`run port $ static $ logger $ app cfg`) and I imported `Network.Wai.Middleware.Static (static)`. I also added `wai-middleware-static >=0.7.0 && < 0.71` to my cabal file.

<s>When I run `stack build` I get:</s>   (**Update: This part is totally my error.** I added the the package to the wrong cabal file.. lame. Importing Network.Wai.Middleware.Static works and serves static files. Leaving the error below in case anyone searches for it and finds it useful.)

```
Could not find module ‘Network.Wai.Middleware.Static’
Perhaps you meant
  Network.Wai.Middleware.Gzip (from wai-extra-3.0.7.1@waiex_GpotceEdscHD6hq9p0wPOJ)
  Network.Wai.Middleware.Jsonp (from wai-extra-3.0.7.1@waiex_GpotceEdscHD6hq9p0wPOJ)
  Network.Wai.Middleware.Local (from wai-extra-3.0.7.1@waiex_GpotceEdscHD6hq9p0wPOJ)
```

Next I tried using servant's `serveDirectory` as follows (simplified):

```
type  API = "users" :> Get   '[JSON]   [Person]
            :<|> "static" :> Raw
server = createPerson :<|> serveDirectory "/static"
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘EitherT ServantErr IO’
arising from a functional dependency between:
  constraint ‘Servant.Server.Internal.Enter.Enter
                (IO Network.Wai.Internal.ResponseReceived)
                (AppM :~> EitherT ServantErr IO)
                (IO Network.Wai.Internal.ResponseReceived)’
    arising from a use of ‘enter’
  instance ‘Servant.Server.Internal.Enter.Enter
              (m a) (m :~> n) (n a)’
    at <no location info>
In the expression: enter (readerToEither cfg) server
In an equation for ‘readerServer’:
    readerServer cfg = enter (readerToEither cfg) server
```

I am a Haskell beginner and I am not familiar with Wai so unsure where to even begin. What changes do I need to make the example code in the Blog post to serve static files?

**Edit**: Since the comments get hidden from the default view, I am pasting my last comment here:

Here is toned down version of Matt's [code](http://blog.gist.github.com/anonymous/a99bc6b36ac2db64878e) from his blog. I consolidated all his modules into a single file, removed all the database stuff but did not clean up the extensions/imports. When I run this code I get the above type mismatch error. Please note that this code does not use Network.Wai.Middleware.Static and I am using qualified import of Servant StaticFiles.

Comment: For the first one, I think you need to add wai-app-static to the build-depends in your .cabal file.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I actually I had put the package in the wrong cabal file. So wai-middleware-static works well. I am playing with the code in the linked blog post and I noticed it chains middlewares so decided to use the static middleware. It probably will take me longer to figure out how to use `wai-app-static` in that context.

Comment: @Ecognium Have you seen [this part](https://haskell-servant.github.io/tutorial/server.html#serving-static-files) of the servant tutorial?

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari Yup but I only understood some parts of it. I got the `:Raw` and `serveDirectory` parts and since I was building on top of the tutorial, which uses Wai and I tried using it with it directly. I just added `:<|> "static" :> Raw` and `:<|> serveDirectory "/static"` and I get the error listed above. May be I need to understand more of the setup to figure out how to integrate with Wai. I tried `lifting` the serveDirectory call but did not help. I am just guessing at this stage :)

Comment: Can you add a minimal but complete example? The error message suggests that this will need a well-placed `lift` but it's hard to tell without being able to look at the whole code.

Comment: @Ecognium I think you're just using the wrong `serveDirectory`. The one from `Network.Wai.Middleware.Static` is actually "lifted" into a proper request handler that'll serve static files under some directory within *servant* already. Just do not import `Network.Wai.Middleware.Static` and simply write [serveDirectory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.4.2/docs/Servant-Utils-StaticFiles.html#v:serveDirectory) "/path/to/your/static/dir". As long as you import `Servant` or `Servant.Utils.StaticFiles`, this will work.

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari @Cactus, here is toned down version of Matt's code from his blog. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a99bc6b36ac2db64878e. I consolidated all his modules into a single file, removed all the database stuff but did not clean up the extensions/imports. When I run this code I get the above type mismatch error. Please note that this code does not use `Network.Wai.Middleware.Static` and I am using qualified import of Servant StaticFiles.

Comment: @Ecognium The `enter` machinery converts your handlers from some monad to another. Your `Reader`-based server has a `Raw`  in it for file serving, so `enter` tries to convert the file-serving thing from `ReaderT ...` to `EitherT ...`, which won't work because `serveDirectory` doesn't live in `ReaderT`. I'm not sure if this is a bug in servant or if it's really more meaningful to define the file-serving handler separately, apart from all the `ReaderT` ones. I have notified the other servant devs. [In the meantime.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a99bc6b36ac2db64878e#comment-1481760)

Comment: @AlpMestanogullari Thank you. Do you mind putting that as the answer and I will accept it? I have not spent much time trying to understand how the whole sever was constructed and was just pattern matching based on what others have done. It has worked ok so far but shows I need to really learn how things work together to make changes to other people's code.

Comment: @Ecognium Sure, I'll try and write up a minimal complete answer. For more questions, feel free to drop by the **#servant** IRC channel on freenode, I would gladly give a shot at some more explanations in real time.

Comment: Note that this is now [an issue](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/157) with a very simple solution that should be included in the next release.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described [in the relevant section of servant's tutorial](https://haskell-servant.github.io/tutorial/server.html#using-another-monad-for-your-handlers), the whole deal with `enter` is to have your request handlers use some monad `m` (in your case some `ReaderT` monad) and to provide a way to convert a computation in `m` to a computation in *servant*'s standard `EitherT ServantErr IO` monad.

The problem here though is that you define a bunch of request handlers in `ReaderT` **and** an additional one to serve static files, and call `enter` on all of these. The `ReaderT` handlers are converted to `EitherT ...` handlers just fine, but `enter` tries to convert the `serveDirectory` call from `ReaderT ...` to `EitherT ...`. This is of course not going to happen anytime soon, since `serveDirectory` isn't a computation in `ReaderT ...` to begin with!

*servant* could arguably just leave `serveDirectory` alone -- at this point I don't have a definite opinion on whether we should do that or not, or if it's better to just have the file-serving handler be glued separately, to the result of calling `enter` on all the other endpoints. Here's how this would look like (look for *-- NEW* to see the changes):

```
type PersonAPI = 
    "users" :> Capture "name" String :> Get '[JSON] Person
   -- NEW: removed Raw from here

-- NEW
type WholeAPI = PersonAPI :<|> Raw

type AppM = ReaderT Config (EitherT ServantErr IO)

userAPI :: Proxy PersonAPI
userAPI = Proxy

-- NEW
wholeAPI :: Proxy WholeAPI
wholeAPI = Proxy

-- NEW: changed 'userAPI' to 'wholeAPI'
app :: Config -> Application
app cfg = serve wholeAPI (readerServer cfg)

readerServer :: Config -> Server WholeAPI
readerServer cfg = enter (readerToEither cfg) server
              :<|> S.serveDirectory "/static" -- NEW

readerToEither :: Config -> AppM :~> EitherT ServantErr IO
readerToEither cfg = Nat $ \x -> runReaderT x cfg

server :: ServerT PersonAPI AppM
server = singlePerson

singlePerson :: String -> AppM Person
singlePerson str = do
    let person = Person { name = "Joe", email = "joe@example.com" }
    return person
```

I have brought this topic to the attention of the other servant developers anyway, thanks! We hadn't really thought about the interaction between `enter` and `serveDirectory` so far (well, I did not).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: The link is broken :-(

Comment: @AdamGłowacki Things have changed a bit since that reply, but this is the documentation you'll want to take a look at, to see how it's done nowadays: https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#using-another-monad-for-your-handlers